# How do I kill a PHP session?

Tags: php, session

I am writing a social networking site, and I am trying to figure out PHP sessions.  At the top of the login page, I call session_destroy(), and I call session_start() at the page where new users are officially registered as users and at the user homepage.  When a user logs out, they are linked to the home page that has session_destroy, but then I can log back in as whatever user just logged out, no matter what username or password I enter.  This is my first time working with sessions, so I'm wondering where I'm supposed to put session_destroy so it actually destroys the session when I logout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/session_destroy) to destroy the session data and [`session_unset`](http://php.net/session_unset) to clear the `$_SESSION` variable respectively.

Furthermore, call `session_regenerate_id(true)` after an authentication attempt to change the current session’s ID and destroy the session data that is still associated to the old session ID.

Comment: Where do I put the session_destroy statement?

Comment: @Nerd With A Vengeance: Call it where you want the current session to be destroyed. Note to call `session_start` before, otherwise the session will not be loaded.

Comment: This answer is not complete. You still need to unset the session variables and invalidate the session cookie if it exists.

Comment: The documentation of `session_unset` says it should only be used for old code that doesn't use `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is by following the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). Here is sample code that erases any session variables, the session cookie and then the session file itself:

```
<?php

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// Delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if( ini_get( "session.use_cookies" ) ) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();

    setcookie(
      session_name()
      , ''
      , time() - 42000
      , $params[ "path"     ]
      , $params[ "domain"   ]
      , $params[ "secure"   ]
      , $params[ "httponly" ]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
if( session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ) { session_destroy(); }
```