# What is the best way to end a session?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I kill a PHP session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239674/how-do-i-kill-a-php-session)

When ending a session, session_destroy() is supposed to destroy the session and the session variables registered with the session. But I've seen lots of codes that unsets all the registered session variables before destroying the session. Please who knows, what is the best practice?

Comment: Use the example from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[session_destroy](http://php.net/session_destroy) erases all of the session data, so it won't be available at the **next** request. It does not unset `$_SESSION` however, and if your application relies on specific values in the `$_SESSION` array, it may behave in a wrong way. But you don't need to unset each session variable, you can end session in this way:

```
$_SESSION = array();    
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Just remember, as the [manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) *In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.*

Answer (score 1):

```
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time()-3600,'/', '', 0, 0);
```

Also unset the `PHPSESSID` cookie on the client-side. http://php.net/session_destroy

Comment: Nice tip, but do not hardcode PHPSESSID, use session_name() instead

Answer (score 0):

Destroying the session will unset all of the variables.  I am not aware of any reason to unset them before destroying.  You MAY however want to unset the variables but KEEP the session.  This can be done by calling session_unset();

Comment: it does not unset the variables, it just erases the session data, but that data was read and populated in the $_SESSION array when session_start() was called